# Fazer unhook após hookado

Tags: delphi

Para fazer um hook eu sei, faço do seguinte modo (Variáveis fictícias):

```
MSGBOX:=GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'),'MessageBox');
  ReadProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,MSGBOX,@OldMSG,sizeof(oldcode),b);

  Jmpmsg.push:=$68;
  Jmpmsg.PProc:=@NewMSG;
  Jmpmsg.ret:=$C3;

  WriteProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,CPA,@Jmpmsg,sizeof(far_jmp),b);
```

Como eu posso estar fazendo o Unhook?

Já tentei do seguinte modo:

```
WriteProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,MSGBOX,@OldMSG,sizeof(Oldcode),b);
```

Mas me da erro :(

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer um backup da memória antes de substituir a chamada original:

```
//faz o backup
ReadProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, CPA, @backup, sizeof(far_jmp), bytesBackup);

//substitui a chamada(faz o hook)
WriteProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, CPA, @Jmpmsg, sizeof(far_jmp), b);

//restaura o backup
WriteProcessMemory(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, CPA, @backup, bytesBackup, b);
```